# R: convert data.frame to data.frame with correct dimensions

Tags: r

I have a data.frame called exp_epis_2 that looks like this:

```
> exp_epis_2[1,]
$V1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5

$V2
 [1]  1 10 13  9  3 

> exp_epis_2[2,]
$V1
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5

$V2
  [1]  1  7  6  9  6
```

I'd prefer to see it like this:

```
1 1
2 10
3 13
4 9
5 3
1 1
2 7
3 6
4 9
5 6
```

I'm very sure this is simple, but I can't seem to find a good answer.

EDIT: per request, here is the output of `dput(head(exp_epis_2))`:

```
dput(head(exp_epis_2))
structure(list(1:91, 1:115, 1:105, 1:98, 1:109, 1:110, c(1L, 
10L, 13L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 
4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), c(1L, 7L, 6L, 
9L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), c(1L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), c(1L, 
8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), c(1L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 
8L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), c(1L, 6L, 10L, 17L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 
5L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L)), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", 
"V2")))
```

Maybe it's easier to see it like this. In my original post, I truncated to 5 elements per list, but in reality exp_epis_2[1, ] has 91 elements and exp_epis_2[2, ] has 115 elements

```
> exp_epis_2[1:2,]
     V1          V2         
[1,] Integer,91  Integer,91 
[2,] Integer,115 Integer,115
```

EDIT 2:

Okay, one improvement:

```
cbind(exp_epis_2[1,][[1]], exp_epis_2[1,][[2]])
```

Gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2   10
 [3,]    3   13
 [4,]    4    9
 [5,]    5    3
```

Good start. Then I tried:

```
current = matrix()
for(i in 1:nrow(exp_epis_2)) {
    rbind(current, cbind(exp_epis_2[i,][[1]], exp_epis_2[i,][[2]]))
}
```

But I can't seem to iteratively rbind....

Comment: Could you please provide your data using `dput(exp_epis)` ?

Comment: @G5W it has 4000 rows....

Comment: Try `dput(head(exp_epis))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
apply(exp_epis_2, 2, unlist)
```

However, be aware that `exp_epis_2` is a matrix, and not, as you seem to think, a data-frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a data frame but it depends on how you load it. Your loading into your data frame in 2 sets but you'd rather load into 1. Another way to store it the way you want could be a matrix.

Comment: Thank you @Yash Mehra, but how can I do this? What commands do I use?